# Schwartz Lemma and non injective analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading a proof on Riemann's mapping theorem and there is a part I don't quite understand. The book uses a lemma which says that if $f:D(0,1) \to D(0,1)$ is analytic and non injective then $|f'(0)| \lt 1$

To show this we set $a=f(0)$ and we use Schwartz' lemma on $φ_a(f(z))$, where $φ_a(z) ={ {z-a} \over 1- \overline az}$, and show that $|(φ_a(f(0))'| \lt1$ because $φ_a(f(z))$ is non injective.

I don't get the last part. Why we get $\lt$ instead of $\le$?

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Schwarz lemma says that if $g:D(0,1)\to D(0,1)$ is analytic and $g(0)=0$, then $|g(z)|\leq |z|$ for all $z$ and $|g'(0)|\leq 1$, and *moreover* that if $|g(z)|=|z|$ for some $z\neq 0$ or $|g'(0)|=1$, then there exists a constant $c$ of norm $1$ such that $g(z)=cz$ for all $z$.  In particular, if $|g'(0)|=1$ then $g$ would be injective.

Comment: Oh boy, was it obvious! I feel kinda stupid. Anyway thanks!